# Von Neumann's ergodic theorem

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Where can I find the proof of Von Neumann's ergodic theorem? Please, give me references or write names of books where I can find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original proof ([pdf](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1076162/pdf/pnas01729-0078.pdf)) is in

> J. von Neumann, "Proof of the quasi-ergodic hypothesis" Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. USA , 18 (1932) pp. 70–82

A simpler proof is due to Halmos, found in

> P.R. Halmos, "Lectures on ergodic theory" , Math. Soc. Japan (1956)

I believe [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821841254) is a reprinting of those lectures.

Comment: An alternative name for the same result is the *mean ergodic theorem* and there's a proof in almost every book on ergodic theory. Terry Tao has a [blog post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/01/30/254a-lecture-8-the-mean-ergodic-theorem/) on it.

Comment: Due to riesz but it is mentiond in Halmos's lectures.

Answer (score 2):

If you want more modern books I recommend P. Walters or K. Petersen books on Ergodic Theory.

Answer (score 0):

Einsiedler. Ward. Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory. P. 32.

Petersen. Ergodic Theory. P. 23.

Brin. Sturk. An Introduction to Dynamical Systems. P. 80.

Krengel. Ergodic Theorems. P. 4.

Halmos. Lectures on Ergodic Theory. P. 16.

Coudene. Ergodic Theory  and  Dynamical Systems. P. 4.

Eisner. Farkas. Haase. Nagel. Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory. P. 139.